# Progress bar in android is not stopping after loading data from json file

Tags: java, android, json

After trying for so many times it didnt worked ,I am retrieving data from database in json format and displaying in android in recyclerview .Once the data is shown the progress bar is not stopping or not getting invisible.
only the progress bar is not working
mainactivity.java

```
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    MobileProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    loadRecyclerViewData();`



`private void loadRecyclerViewData(){

    //to fetch data we do string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_Data,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                //JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
               // JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("contact");//Array name

                //converting the string to json array object

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                //JSONArray arr=array.getJSONArray("Array");

                for(int i=0;i< array.length();i++){
                    //getting product object from json array

                    JSONObject jsonObjec = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    ListUser user=new ListUser(
                            jsonObjec.getString("name"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("email"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("contactno"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("date"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("time"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("requirement_type"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("message")

                    );

                            listUsers.add(user);

                }



               adapter=new MyAdapter(listUsers, getApplicationContext());//data from MyAdapter constructor
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError  volleyError) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}`
```

anyone try to help

Comment: MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); define inside  public void onResponse(String response) {}

Comment: tried but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this after setting your adapter use `MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

```
 adapter=new MyAdapter(listUsers, getApplicationContext());//data from 
 MyAdapter constructorrecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Not working...the progress bar suddenly gone..it should show user that data is being fetched and then go invisible..  when i run the app i cant even see the progress bar

Comment: Your getting API response faster so progress invisible happened

Comment: i want to display till the data loads ...the user comes to know that data is being loading

Comment: Actually after data loaded only progress bar visibility gone

Comment: If your data loading slow automatically progress visibility to the user

Comment: That's not an issue

Answer (score 1):

set visibility gone in `onResponse` and `onErrorResponse`

```
private void loadRecyclerViewData(){

    //to fetch data we do string request
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            URL_Data,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {
                //JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
               // JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("contact");//Array name

                //converting the string to json array object

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                //JSONArray arr=array.getJSONArray("Array");

                for(int i=0;i< array.length();i++){
                    //getting product object from json array

                    JSONObject jsonObjec = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    ListUser user=new ListUser(
                            jsonObjec.getString("name"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("email"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("contactno"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("date"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("time"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("requirement_type"),
                            jsonObjec.getString("message")

                    );

                            listUsers.add(user);

                }



               adapter=new MyAdapter(listUsers, getApplicationContext());//data from MyAdapter constructor
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
               MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);//change here

            }

            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);//change here
            }
        }
    },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError  volleyError) {
            MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);//change here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}
```

Comment: Not working...the progress bar suddenly gone when i run the app..it should show user that data is being fetched and then go invisible..  when i run the app i cant even see the progress bar

Comment: ProgressBar dismiss instantly because you are fetching too small data and it loads very fast, if data is big then eventually can see ProgressBar. if you want to see how it work then set debug point and see how it become gone...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try this code
    private void loadRecyclerViewData(){

        //to fetch data we do string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL_Data,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
        MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(s);
                   // JSONArray array=jsonObject.getJSONArray("contact");//Array name

                    //converting the string to json array object

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                    //JSONArray arr=array.getJSONArray("Array");

                    for(int i=0;i< array.length();i++){
                        //getting product object from json array

                        JSONObject jsonObjec = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        ListUser user=new ListUser(
                                jsonObjec.getString("name"),
                                jsonObjec.getString("email"),
                                jsonObjec.getString("contactno"),
                                jsonObjec.getString("date"),
                                jsonObjec.getString("time"),
                                jsonObjec.getString("requirement_type"),
                                jsonObjec.getString("message")

                        );

                                listUsers.add(user);

                    }



                   adapter=new MyAdapter(listUsers, getApplicationContext());//data from MyAdapter constructor
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

                catch (JSONException e) {
        MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },

                new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError  volleyError) {
        MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }`
```

Comment: Not working...the progress bar suddenly gone..it should show user that data is being fetched and then go invisible..  when i run the app i cant even see the progress bar

Answer (score 0):

Just use,

```
MobileProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

when you want to stop progress bar.